# Retopology issue- Geometry stretching and I'm not sure why

Tags: sculpting, baking, multiresolution, retopology

I made this sculpt in Blender, and then try to do retopology. Thinking I was done, I added the multires modifier, and the shrinkwrap modifier, so I'll be able to project the details from the high poly, and then bake a normal map. But when I add the modifiers, it's causing stretching for some reason. I am not sure why, or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

High Poly
[image: High Poly]

Retopo Low Poly
[image: Retopo Low Poly]

Retopo With Modifiers
[image: Retopo With Modifiers]

Comment: could you please label each picture?

Comment: multires modifier isnt great. I would use a different workflow.

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clear. The pictures should be labeled now.

GifCo- What workflow would you use instead of the multires?